# List comprehensions and tuples in Julia

Tags: julia, list-comprehension

I am trying to do in Julia what this Python code does. (Find all pairs from the two lists whose combined value is above 7.)

```
#Python    
def sum_is_large(a, b):
    return a + b > 7

l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [4,5,6]
l3 = [(a,b) for a in l1 for b in l2 if sum_is_large(a, b)]
print(l3)
```

There is no `if` for list comprehensions in Julia. And if I use `filter()`, I'm not sure if I can pass two arguments. So my best suggestion is this:

```
#Julia
function sum_is_large(pair)
    a, b = pair
    return a + b > 7 
end

l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [4,5,6]

l3 = filter(sum_is_large, [(i,j) for i in l1, j in l2])
print(l3)
```

I don't find this very appealing. So my question is, is there a better way in Julia?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the very popular package Iterators.jl, in Julia:

```
using Iterators       # install using Pkg.add("Iterators")
filter(x->sum(x)>7,product(l1,l2))
```

is an iterator producing the pairs. So to get the same printout as the OP:

```
l3iter = filter(x->sum(x)>7,product(l1,l2))
for p in l3iter println(p); end
```

The iterator approach is potentially much more memory efficient. Ofcourse, one could just `l3 = collect(l3iter)` to get the pair vector.

@user2317519, just curious, is there an equivalent iterator form for python?

Comment: I like the iterators. 

You can do a similar thing in python if you import itertools.


However, I'm afraid I made a mistake when trying to boil down my question to a simple example. My main problem is with the tuple as argument. 


Can we pretend that the function sum_is_large() is really rather complicated, and that it needs to use the a and b variables repeatedly. Is there a way to pass these two variables without doing something like
a, b = pair?

Comment: `a` and `b` are addressable as `x[1]` and `x[2]` in `bigfunc`. You can also do `x->bigfunc(x...)` and then define `bigfunc(a,b)`. This code detour should not cost too much in efficiency, if anything.

Comment: @DanGetz in python there is [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) which basically contains similar iterators that julia's `Iterators.jl`.

Comment: @DanGetz, I wonder if you could comment on David P. Sanders's answer below. What are the advantages, in 2021, of using ``Iterators.jl`` now that generators are (if I understand correctly) available in base Julia?

Comment: @PatrickT Of course you are right. As Julia changes, so should the answers on Stackoverflow change. David Sanders's answer looks good (and the running times should be the same - though I haven't checked). In fact, many code snippets in SO can be regarded as test code and SO would be wise to provide mechanism to provide pass/fail on tests and allow tracking of tests over versions of 'tags' (which represent working environments). If SO has good NLP bots or comment reviewers they would pick this idea and upvote it.

Comment: @DanGetz, Oh that would be excellent indeed. Another thing (which SO couldn't do much about) is that search engines tend to send you to the most viewed answers and often that means landing on "old" questions. Thanks for your feedback about David's answer. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Guards (`if`) are now available in Julia v0.5 (currently in the release-candidate stage):

```
julia> v1 = [1, 2, 3];

julia> v2 = [4, 5, 6];

julia> v3 = [(a, b) for a in v1, b in v2 if a+b > 7]
3-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (3,5)
 (2,6)
 (3,6)
```

Note that generators are also now available:

```
julia> g = ( (a, b) for a in v1, b in v2 if a+b > 7 )
Base.Generator{Filter{##18#20,Base.Prod2{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1}}},##17#19}(#17,Filter{##18#20,Base.Prod2{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1}}}(#18,Base.Prod2{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1}}([1,2,3],[4,5,6])))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option similar to the one of @DanGetz using also `Iterators.jl`:

```
function expensive_fun(a, b)
    return (a + b)
end
```

Then, if the condition is also complicated, it can be defined as a function:

```
condition(x) = x > 7
```

And last, filter the results:

```
>>> using Iterators
>>> result = filter(condition, imap(expensive_fun, l1, l2))
```

`result` is an iterable that is only computed when needed (inexpensive) and can be collected `collect(result)` if required.

The one-line if the filter condition is simple enough would be:

```
>>> result = filter(x->(x > 7), imap(expensive_fun, l1, l2))
```

Note: `imap` works natively for arbitrary number of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
julia> filter(pair -> pair[1] + pair[2] > 7,  [(i, j) for i in l1, j in l2])
3-element Array{Tuple{Any,Any},1}:
 (3,5)
 (2,6)
 (3,6)
```

although I'd agree it doesn't look like it ought to be the best way...

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised nobody mentions the ternary operator to implement the conditional:

```
julia> l3 = [sum_is_large((i,j)) ? (i,j) : nothing for i in l1, j in l2]
3x3 Array{Tuple,2}:
 nothing  nothing  nothing
 nothing  nothing  (2,6)  
 nothing  (3,5)    (3,6)
```

or even just a normal `if` block within a compound statement, i.e.

```
[ (if sum_is_large((x,y)); (x,y); end) for x in l1, y in l2 ]
```

which gives the same result.

I feel this result makes a lot more sense than `filter()`, because in julia the `a in A, b in B` construct is interpreted *dimensionally*, and therefore the output is in fact an *"array comprehension"* with appropriate dimensionality, which clearly in many cases would be advantageous and presumably the desired behaviour (whether we include a conditional or not).

Whereas filter will always return a vector. Obviously, if you *really* want a vector result you can always `collect` the result; or for a conditional list comprehension like the one here, you can simply remove `nothing` elements from the array by doing `l3 = l3[l3 .!= nothing]`.

Presumably this is still clearer and no less efficient than the `filter()` approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@vcomp` (vector comprehension) macro in VectorizedRoutines.jl to do Python-like comprehensions:

```
using VectorizedRoutines
Python.@vcomp Int[i^2 for i in 1:10] when i % 2 == 0 # Int[4, 16, 36, 64, 100]
```